# To test a POST request for an authenticated route in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-testing

I want to test a post request for a route with authentication required(Knox from Django Rest Framework). Here the post request should object for a logged in user.

Following is **urls.py**

```
path('cards', addCard.as_view(), name="cards"),
```

Following is addCard view

```
class addCard(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CardSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrNot]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        card = serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
        return Response({'card': CardSerializer(card, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,})

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.cards.order_by('-id')
```

Following is the test case, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63897151/8245191), I got 401!=201 error, clearly Unauthorized user.

```
class addCardAPIViewTestCase(APITestCase):
    url = reverse("cards")

    def setUp(self):
        self.username = "john"
        self.email = "john@snow.com"
        self.password = "you_know_nothing"
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(self.username,
                                                     self.password)

        self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.user)

    def test_create_cards(self):

        client = APIClient()
        client.login(username=self.username,
                 password=self.password)
        client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + self.token.key)

        response = client.post(self.url,{
            "bank": "Citibank",
            "card_number": "5618073505538298",
            "owner_name": "c1",
            "cvv": "121",
            "expiry_date_month": "03",
            "expiry_date_year": "2023"
        },format='json')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

Comment: `client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + self.token.key)`. Doesn't this line set authentication header?

Comment: Yes, while checking from POSTMAN, we insert  Authentication Header with a Token, I believe this is how I handled here to authenticate user, correct me If I am wrong. I am open to suggestions, if there is any alternative way to test a POST request which requires login, in my case only username and password.

Comment: just remove `client.login` and `client.credentials` lines for testing unauthorized user and it should return 401

Comment: Yes, it returns 401 after removing `client.login`, `client.credentials`, I wanted to make a successful POST hence 201 is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`client.force_authenticate(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication)

```
class addCardAPIViewTestCase(APITestCase):
    # Rest of your code
    def test_create_cards(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)
        response = self.client.post(self.url, {
            "bank": "Citibank",
            "card_number": "5618073505538298",
            "owner_name": "c1",
            "cvv": "121",
            "expiry_date_month": "03",
            "expiry_date_year": "2023"
        }, format='json')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `client.login` **OR** `client.credentials` if you want to test for authenticated user. The first one should be used if you authenticate users via `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` (also consider `client.force_login` for better performance) and second one for token authentication. Using both of them at the same time is meaningless.

Comment: I tried using them separately, one at a time, still getting 401. I used `self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)` as suggested by @JPG and it worked.